# I am trying to write a Python code that reads each item in a list and add and find the average of that list with certain conditions

Tags: python, list

So I'm trying to add all the numbers of a list and divide that sum by how many numbers in that list are not equal to 0. The code does not include the part where I summed all the numbers together. What I did in this part of my code is that I tried to check each individual item in a list one at a time. Eventually, it would tell me how many numbers were not equal to zero with the variable sum_div.

```
b=4
c=0
d=6
e=0

I_list = [ b, c, d, e]

sum_div = 0

ip = I_list[0]

for i in range(0, len(I_list), 1) :
    while ip != 0:
        sum_div += 1
    elif ip == 0:
        sum_div += 0
    
print(sum_div)
```

sum_div was supposed to equal 2 in this case.

Comment: This code doesn't work. You can't have an `elif` without an `if`. Try to provide an [mcve]

Comment: `sum_div += 0` doesn't seem like it'll have much effect on anything

Comment: You may want to print out your code and follow the logic line-by-line with a pencil, ensuring that you execute each line exactly as the computer would, noting down variable values as you go. Otherwise, ask your teacher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to filter out the elements that are `0` then determine the len of that list. Then just divide the sum by that length to compute the average (of non-zero elements)

```
>>> sum(I_list) / len([i for i in I_list if i])
5.0
```

Technically you could also guard against an empty list, or a list of all zeroes

```
try:
    average = sum(I_list) / len([i for i in I_list if i])
except ZeroDivisionError:
    average = whatever_here  # don't know what you'd want in this case
```

Answer (score 0):

Cory's answer above is a slick solution, but your's is almost there as well. You'd just need to make a slight change:

```py
b=4
c=0
d=6
e=0

I_list = [ b, c, d, e]

sum_div = 0

for i in range(0, len(I_list), 1) :
    ip = I_list[i] # Make sure to update your value

    if ip != 0:  # Use an if instead of a while
        sum_div += 1
    elif ip == 0
        sum_div += 0

print(sum_div)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which has better performance is using the numpy library

```
# import numpy 
import numpy as np

# create a numpy array (just feed it the same list you created)
I_array = np.array([b, c, d, e])

# calculate the array sum using np.sum()
array_sum = np.sum(I_array)

# I_array > 0 returns array of True or False for each item depending on how it matches the condition of not-equal zero.
# np.sum() evaluates all True as 1 and all False as 0.
amount_of_non_zeros = np.sum(I_array != 0)

# sum of array divided by amount of non-zeros
array_sum / amount_of_non_zeros
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I_list =[4, 0, 6, 0]
sum_div = 0
for i in I_list:
    if i != 0:
        sum_div += 1
print(sum_div)
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers and post a short explanation why your code works.